# Stellar Account Viewer not allowing access

Tags: security

I use Stellar Account Viewer for its ease of use and had no problems until now. Today though it is refusing to recognize my Private key (which is double, treble backed up). Has there been a recent change?

I've always been careful regarding malware and the like and have no problems with other coins and their wallets. Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is it giving you an error message? Without more details we are kinda just guessing at what the problem could be.

Comment: Also, not quite sure how this relates to security. Seems like it more relates to the account viewer.